# Unable to use Angular CLI to create app: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...bgwj8Xr2oElY7PTvOKwwu'

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Initially I couldn't get NPM to install Angular. It kept timing out and throwing errors. Eventually, I was able to install Angular after installing Yarn.

Now the Angular CLI doesn't seem to work.

Attempts to fix:
* Uninstalled and re-installed Node
* Cleared npm's cache
* Uninstalled and re-installed Angular
* Ran all commands as admin
* Installed Yarn

I've been at this for hours now. I'm at my whit's end. This is a brand new computer. I've installed Angular on two other machines with no problems.

````
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\shari\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--quiet'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.2
4 verbose npm-session e63fb575bc1fd219
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
. 
.
.

2809 silly saveTree angularmaterial@0.0.0
2809 silly saveTree +-- @angular/animations@9.1.1
2809 silly saveTree +-- @angular/common@9.1.1
2809 silly saveTree +-- @angular/forms@9.1.1
2809 silly saveTree +-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.1
2809 silly saveTree +-- @angular/platform-browser@9.1.1
2809 silly saveTree +-- @angular/router@9.1.1
2809 silly saveTree +-- rxjs@6.5.5
2809 silly saveTree | `-- tslib@1.11.1
2809 silly saveTree +-- tslib@1.11.1
2809 silly saveTree `-- zone.js@0.10.3
2810 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...bgwj8Xr2oElY7PTvOKwwu'
2810 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2810 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Users\shari\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
2810 verbose stack     at C:\Users\shari\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
2810 verbose stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
2810 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2811 verbose cwd C:\Users\shari\Documents\Angular\Angular Material\angularmaterial
2812 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
2813 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\shari\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
2814 verbose node v12.16.2
2815 verbose npm  v6.14.4
2816 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...bgwj8Xr2oElY7PTvOKwwu'
2817 verbose exit [ 1, true ]```
````

Comment: Have you uninstalled and reinstalled @angular/cli globally? I see above that you wrote that you've done something to angular... I'm asking this just to be sure you're referring to cli.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I did, but I did it again just to be sure. This time I received the following error: ```CREATE angularmaterial/e2e/src/app.po.ts (301 bytes)
- Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ependencies":{"rxjs":'```

Comment: when you uninstalled @angular/cli (`sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`), did you `sudo npm cache verify` before `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` again?

Comment: This is a Windows machine.

Comment: Just get rid of the `sudo` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my install was timing out due to a slow internet connection. The install would fail at different places, depending on when it timed out.

After I moved to a new place with faster internet, I initially got the same error message. However, after I used the `npm cache clean --force` to clear my cache, I was able to install Angular.